Weird vertical line in altium
Anyone know what is that green/yellow line that exist in the PCB? How to disable it?


Can you clarify which "green/yellow line" the issue is about?

Is it no possible to select it?

The vertical line is a snap guide. See: https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/pcb-grids-guides#snap-guides
